# Git script from a Windows batch file

Tags: git

I am able to open a git shell in Windows with this command from a batch script:

```
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

Now, I want to run a simple script involing git commands.
What I tried so far is to put them after that line, but seems not to be working.
I also tried the following:

```
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login script.sh
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login script.bat
```

but, in both cases I'm not able to see the output. The git shell just stays alive for half a second.

Am I following the wrong way?

Comment: Unless the script pauses at the end, once the script terminates, the process will terminate. This is normal, you will have to figure out a way to execute them that will pause at the end.

Comment: If you have placed that start command in a batch file, why not simply call `sh` directly instead of using `start`?

Comment: In other words, in your batch file, why not simply use `"%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login` and then a separate line with `PAUSE` ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future having the same problem, I got the solution:

```
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login script.sh
```

In *script.sh* just put at the end the following command in order to pause the shell:

```
read -n1 -r -p "Git script finished, press any key to exit" key
```